# Minimum set of packages for headless LibreOffice install?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, headless

I need to install LO on a server, and run headless transforms between various document types. The full LO install is about 1 GB, most of which is useless in a server environment.

There's now a `libreoffice-core-nogui` package, but it doesn't appear to do anything useful. To convert a text file to pdf, for example, I also needed to install `libreoffice-java-common` and `libreoffice-writer-nogui`.

Is this a usable minimum set of packages for general document-to-document transforms, or should I be installing something else?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for a LibreOffice site like https://ask.libreoffice.org/c/english/5 . I don't see anything specific to Ubuntu here.

Comment: Based on its `apt show` record, `libreoffice-nogui` looks like a better candidate than `libreoffice-core-nogui`

Comment: Try it. Install `ubuntu-server` in a VM (Virtual Machine), add your set of packages, and test document conversions. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @steeldriver: I think you're right. It also installs `libreoffice-calc-nogui`, which is good for previews.

Comment: @waltinator: already doing this. Unfortunately, 'lather, rinse, repeat' is never-ending, since everything on top (Alfresco) is difficult to install.